# GetHashCode for multiple boolean values

Tags: c#, boolean, gethashcode

In the following StackOverflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263400/what-is-the-best-algorithm-for-an-overridden-system-object-gethashcode) Jon Skeets answer specifies one good implementation is ...

```
// Note: Not quite FNV!
public override int GetHashCode()
{
    unchecked // Overflow is fine, just wrap
    {
        int hash = (int) 2166136261;
        // Suitable nullity checks etc, of course :)
        hash = (hash * 16777619) ^ bool1.GetHashCode();
        hash = (hash * 16777619) ^ bool2.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

What if the two fields are both bools.  Would this still be a good implementation or would this be overkill?  If this is overkill what is the recommended approach for implementing `GetHashCode` when all fields are bool types?

In my case I am only comparing two bools.

Comment: How many boolean fields do you have? Say, more than thirty or less than thirty?

Comment: It still works quite well.  I suppose you can turn the set of booleans to a bit field, which maps well when there are less than 32 (one fore each bit in an `int`).  However, the complexity/speed trade-offs would be a wash either way.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight two Booleans, modified question to reflect this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you have fewer than thirty `bool` fields you can implement a [*perfect*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_hash_function) hashing scheme by treating each `bool` as a single bit in the value of hash code. By "perfect" I mean that hash equality would be equivalent to actual equality (as opposed to "ordinary" hashing schemes, in which actual equality implies hash equality, but not vice versa).

The code would look like this:

```
public override int GetHashCode() {
    var hash = 0;
    if (field1)
        hash |= 1<<0;
    if (field2)
        hash |= 1<<1;
    if (field3)
        hash |= 1<<2;
    if (field4)
        hash |= 1<<3;
    return hash;
}
```

Comment: You said "caching schemes" twice in the answer did you mean to say "hashing schemes"?

Comment: Why fewer than 30 fields?  Surely the limitation is 32.

Comment: @Kyle 31 actually. Many implmentations that use the hash code (for example [in HashSet](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,3000888850fdc510)) only use the lower 31 bits and ignore the sign bit. They do this because they use negative values as sentinel values to represent uninitialized data.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Ah, you are right, of course it's hashing! Thank you very much!